# what does DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION do?

Tags: android, android-intent, message, broadcast

I am implementing GCM for my project and I was getting into details.

I read the google documentation regarding this matter, but I could not find anything regarding the below code.
This code is in a helper class and gets called from there.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**What does DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION do?**

Where can I get all the list of these constants that can do different thins via intents?

- Why are we using sendBroadcast here?
- What does displaying a message have to do with broadcasts?

Comment: I think this method was used in GCM demo application to show message in textview.. And this action is custom , this is not from predefind Actions

Comment: so removing it will cause no harm eh ?

Comment: no.. It should not be.